# Flutter Offline Images Before Uploading

Tags: firebase, image, flutter, caching, offline

So I'm trying to build an offline-first application with Firebase storage images but am running into an issue. I don't want the user to know when an image is being uploaded to Firebase or not and I want to show the image from the user's local storage immediately. Basically, I want the app to render the local storage image if the image isn't uploaded yet.

I currently use `CachedNetworkImage` but this requires that the image has been uploaded.

I could create the image URL before uploading it and somehow reference that URL with the local image but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Any thoughts?

**Edit:**
I think I'm going to go with this approach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzrP93xNW8g
It's basically using Firestore track what's been uploaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Without code we're guessing of course, but making some assumptions here...
Assuming this means not all images will be in their local storage forever:
Could you simply check if an image exists in firebase and if it doesn't present the local image? That is, conditionally build a vanilla Image widget pulling from local storage or a CachedNetworkImage from a URL based on a variable. Perhaps you have a MyImage object with a URL property and pick which widget to build by checking if that is null in the build function.